# Actionscript 2.0 Cursor Settings

Tags: cursor, actionscript-2

I am making a point and click horror game and I am wondering on how I can change cursors from being the arrow to another cursor. the examples are from a game called Bad Dream: Series.
[image: The regular cursor]

[image: The cursor after moving it to the door area]

The cursor changes from the first picture to the second picture that has the cursor on the door area.